# How to delete persisted jobs in Quartz?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

In my web application, we are using a JDBC datastore to persist details about jobs & triggers.
I have a job named X created before which is also persisted in database.
I want to get rid of this job.
I tried using schedulerInstance.deleteJob() function to delete the job.
It gets deleted, but the next time i restart my tomcat server, Job magically appears again and seen in DB also. What is happening here?
I want to know how to delete the job permanently.
Can some one pls help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like something in your code on startup is re-registering the Job which then gets persisted back into the database.

I would search through your code to find out what it does on Startup and see if you can find any references to your Job.

Comment: Yes, thats what i was thinking. But i could not find anything. Doesnt the deleteJob() function removes the job from db as well?!

Comment: Hmmm... When the reboot happens, does the Job still run? Or does it just have the appropriate records entered into the JDBCJobStore? If its not running it could be since the Job is present the appropriate database records get created on boot. (My knowledge of Quartz JDBCJobStore isn't that high.)

Comment: Ohh! The job runs and also has the records in DB.

Comment: Then theres some BootStrap going on that is re-registering the job on Start Up. You could debug and step through the startup to see if you can find where it gets started from to disable it or just delete the job code...

Comment: I could figure out the problem. What was actually happening was that there was another tomcat server used by a peer which was using the same db as mine. The code base in both was the same. However i had modified code a little bit to delete the old job and create a new one..!!